# Cannot Seem to delete UL LI tab from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I'd like to request someones help/support and guidance so as to be able to remove a UL LI tab from a standalone function, provided that the user has selected an "active tab".

As my code stands right now, it seem it does a great job at removing the tab content minus the LI tab itself. So there's kind of (2) things that i'd like to be able to accomplish:

1. Deleting the "Active" (selected) UL LI tab from calling a function
2. After deleting/removing the tab, move the active (selected tab) to the adjacent tab on the left.

Here's the HTML markup in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(109,109,109);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(109,109,109);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(109,109,109);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(109,109,109);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(109,109,109);
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}   
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid rgb(109,109,109);
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
   padding: 2px;
}
.tab_wrapper {
    background: rgb(231,231,226);
    height: 100%;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 10px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    init_form()

});



function init_form() {

    //INITIALIZE TABS
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs").on('click', 'li' ,function() {// OLD: $("ul.tabs li").on('click', function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        //debug: alert(activeTab)
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;       
    });

}

function delete_tab() {

    var tab =  $('ul.tabs li.active a').attr('href')

    $(tab).remove()

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="table-container">

    <div id="container">

        <div id="main" style="display: inline-block; width: 983px;">

            <ul class="tabs">
                <div class="close_wrapper"><li><a href="#tab1">XAL-2017-482336</a><span class="close"></span></li></div>
                <div class="close_wrapper"><li><a href="#tab2">A-2017-00471</a><span class="close"></span></li></div>
                <div class="close_wrapper"><li><a href="#tab3">A-2017-00123</a><span class="close"></span></li></div>
            </ul>   

            <div class="tab_container">

                <div class="tab_wrapper">


                    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">this is tab 1</div>

                    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">this is tab 2</div>

                    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">this is tab 3</div>     

                </div><!-- END DIV TAB wrapper -->

            </div><!-- END DIV TAB container -->

    </div><!-- END DIV main -->

    </div><!-- END DIV container -->

</div><!-- END DIV table-container -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi bobby.. so what's the different between this "delete" and "close" which I have done previously?

Comment: I'd like to add some functionaliy to have the user to also be able to delete a tab from the click of a button as I will be hooking up a database to this later on.

Comment: `the click of a button` where is this button located? i can only imagine `close` button on each tab

Comment: I will insert an icon somewhere on my page and the user will click a delete button and the selected (active tab) will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/y4z1j03z/3/

Modifying from previous fiddle, you can wrap `close` tab event handler into a function that receives `tabID` as parameter.

```js
// 
function init_form() {
  // INITIALIZE TABS
  $(".tab_content").hide(); // Hide all content
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); // Activate first tab
  $(".tab_content:first").show(); // Show first tab content
}


init_form();


// Delete button event handler
$("#deleteTab").on("click", function(e) {
 var tabId = $("#tabIdToDelete").val();
  removeTab(tabId);
  
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});


// Close tab click event handler
$('.close').on('click', function() {
 var tabId = $(this).parent().find("a").attr("href");
  removeTab(tabId);
});


// Tab Click event handler
$("ul.tabs li").on('click', 'a', function() {
 // console.log("tab clicked", this);
  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); // Remove any "active" class
  $(this).parent("li").addClass("active"); // Add "active" class to selected tab
  $(".tab_content").hide(); // Hide all tab content
  
  // Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
  $(activeTab).fadeIn(); // Fade in the active content
  return false;
});


// Remove tab based on the given tabId
function removeTab(tabId) {

  // Find the parent li based on href information
  var parentLi = $("li").find("a[href='" + tabId + "']").parent();
  // console.log("close clicked", tabId, parentLi);
  
  // If parentLi is not found, exit and do nothing
  if (parentLi.length == 0) {
   return;
  }
  
  // Get the index of the li, and check if it's active tab
  var indexToClose = $("ul.tabs li").index(parentLi);
  var isActive = parentLi.hasClass("active");
  // console.log("close clicked, indexToClose?", indexToClose, "isActive?", isActive);
  
  var tabsLength = $("ul.tabs li").length;
  // If current tab is active, find the prev tab, otherwise do nothing (just close the tab)
  if (isActive) {
   var nextIndex = (indexToClose - 1);
    if (nextIndex < 0) {
     nextIndex = indexToClose + 1;
    }
    
    //console.log("close clicked", "tabs-length", tabsLength, "nextIndex", nextIndex);
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(nextIndex).find("a").click();
  }
  
  $(parentLi).remove(); // Removes tab
  $(tabId).remove(); // Removes content

 tabsLength = $("ul.tabs li").length;
  if (tabsLength == 0) {
   $(".tabs").hide();
    $(".tab_container").hide();
  }
  
  // Extra: remove deleted tab from dropdown option
  var optionToDelete = $("#tabIdToDelete").find("option[value='" + tabId + "']");
  optionToDelete.remove();
  
}
```

```css
body, * {
  font-family: monospace;
}

#main {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(109, 109, 109);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(109, 109, 109);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 32px;
  // line-height: 32px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(109, 109, 109);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(109, 109, 109);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(109, 109, 109);
  border-left: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.tabs li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  // border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

html ul.tabs li.active,
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid rgb(109, 109, 109);
  border-top: none;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  width: 99%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.tab_wrapper {
  background: rgb(231, 231, 226);
  height: 100%;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.close {
  width: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.close:hover {
  color: red;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Tab to delete
  <select id="tabIdToDelete">
    <option value="">--select Tab--</option>
    <option value="#tab1">tab1</option>
    <option value="#tab2">tab2</option>
    <option value="#tab3">tab3</option>
    <option value="#tab4">tab4</option>
  </select>
  <button id="deleteTab">Delete</button>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <div class="close_wrapper">
      <li>
        <a href="#tab1">1XAL-2017-482336</a>
        <span class="close">x</span>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="close_wrapper">
      <li>
        <a href="#tab2">2A-2017-00471</a>
        <span class="close">x</span>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="close_wrapper">
      <li>
        <a href="#tab3">3A-2017-00123</a>
        <span class="close">x</span>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="close_wrapper">
      <li>
        <a href="#tab4">4A-2017-00456</a>
        <span class="close">x</span>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab_container">
    <div class="tab_wrapper">

      <!--BEGIN DIV TAB 1 -->
      <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
        TAB 1
        <br/> Nie Li glanced towards Xiao Ning’er. She had a slim figure, was wearing a short, yellow skirt, and a pair of high heeled boots. Her black was hair draped over her shoulders. She had bright, clear eyes, curved eyebrows, and long eyelashes that
        slightly trembled. Her flawless white skin revealed touches of pink, and delicate lips were like rose petals.
      </div>
      <!--END DIV TAB 1 -->

      <!--BEGIN DIV TAB 2 -->
      <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
        TAB 2
        <br/> Aside from having a charming feel to her, she had an indescribable, wild beauty and a cold expression on her face that added a different kind of taste. Nie Li’s eyes went heavy when he remembered that Xiao Ning’er was the first child of the Winged
        Dragon Family. She was part of one of the seven Noble families. Her soul force talent was only beneath Ye Ziyun. Before Glory City was destroyed, she had already become a Silver rank Demon Spiritualist. Together with Ye Ziyun, they became the
        younger generation’s twin gemini.
      </div>
      <!--END DIV TAB 2 -->

      <!--BEGIN DIV TAB 3 -->
      <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
        TAB 3
        <br/> The only thing is, in order to curry favor with one of the three Major families, the Winged Dragon Family forced Xiao Ning’er to marry into the Sacred Family. She would’ve had to marry Shen Yue’s elder brother. But she was unwilling, hence, she
        left her family and went into the St. Ancestral Mountain’s Black Devil Forest and never came back. She’s an unyielding woman.
      </div>
      <!--END DIV TAB 3 -->

      <!--BEGIN DIV TAB 4 -->
      <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
        TAB 4
        <br/> Nie Li felt sorry for Xiao Ning’er. If given the chance, he will definitely help Xiao Ning’er in this life. But if asked if he had any affection for Xiao Ning’er, there would be none. In Nie Li’s heart, there’s only Ye Ziyun. “In the Fighter
        and Demon Spiritualist tests in two months time, I hope that there will be a few 1-star Bronze rank Demon Spiritualists. Both myself and the Holy Orchid Institute will feel proud of you!” Shen Xiu laughed.
      </div>
      <!--END DIV TAB 4 -->

    </div>
    <!-- END DIV main  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this give u an idea. Just simple update in your code

https://codepen.io/jaigtz88/pen/ZaVyRx

```
<ul class="tabs">
   <div class="close_wrapper" class="tab1"><li><a href="#tab1" class="tab1">XAL-2017-482336</a><span class="close"></span></li></div>
   <div class="close_wrapper" class="tab2"><li><a href="#tab2" class="tab2">A-2017-00471</a><span class="close"></span></li></div>
   <div class="close_wrapper" class="tab3"><li><a href="#tab3" class="tab3">A-2017-00123</a><span class="close"></span></li></div>
</ul>

var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("class");

$('.'+activeTab).parent().prependTo("ul");

$('#'+activeTab).fadeIn();
```